# Mysql Select COL multiple times for different values

Tags: mysql, select

This is the Table Structure:

```
ID PID KEY VALUE
1 2 CITY NEW YORK
2 2 COUNTRY UNITED STATES
3 2 STATE NEW YORK
4 1 CITY NEW JERSEY
```

and so on..
what I want is to get/filter the Result like

```
Where (KEY = CITY and VALUE = NEW YORK) 
      AND (key = country AND VALUE= UNITED STATES)
```

That's returning empty rows!

Comment: What do you expect it to return?

Comment: There are many Countries and Cities if I search only for the Results which has Country = United States it works perfect I want to get the specific Result Where the Country = United States and City = New York

Comment: IF I use Where (KEY = CITY and VALUE = NEW YORK) 
      OR (key = country AND VALUE= UNITED STATES) it works but return ALL United States Data

Comment: Why do you have them as different rows instead of different columns?

Comment: Ah, yeah, been there, done that. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self `JOIN`.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM my_table t1
INNER JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.pid = t2.pid
WHERE t1.key = 'city' and t1.value = 'new york'
  AND t2.key = 'country' and t2.value = 'united states';
```

Comment: could there be a different method to get these results? I mean assume you're not allowed to make the above query! for example: You're at for each loop foreach($search_terms as $k=>$v){
    $term = addslashes_gpc($v);
    
     
     $search .= "{$searchand}(m.value LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}' AND m.meta_key LIKE '{$n}{$k}{$n}')";
    
    $searchand = ' AND ';
   
   }

Comment: $search_terms['country']=$_GET['country'];$search_terms['state']=$_GET['state'];

Comment: @user1147048: sorry, it's freaking hard to read code in the comments. Could you post it pastebin or something like that?

Comment: In this case, you can't do this, because a column can't have two values at the same time. That's why you need a self-join. If you're in control of that meta, you might want to concat values together. Something like: "city=new york&country=united_states". Then you'll be able to test it against of series of LIKE clauses.

Comment: is it possible to write your answer in a foreach loop?

Comment: If you have access only to `where` clause, you can't.

Comment: what do you think about this query: http://paste2.org/p/1865107
it generate this error: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: your query looks like this `a = 1 and b and c = 2` where `b` is your subselect. I think, mysql doesn't like that. also, I think you have unbalanced parens there.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a table with different types of values being held in the same column, with a field identifying each set (PID). Is that correct?

If that's so, then you're going to need a self-join here:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT cityTable.PID
FROM
    tableName AS cityTable
JOIN
    tableName AS countryTable
    ON cityTable.PID = countryTable.PID
WHERE
    cityTable.key = "city"
    AND
    cityTable.value = "NEW YORK"
    AND
    countryTable.key = "country"
    AND
    countryTable.value = "UNITED STATES";
```